# I cannot passing parameters on method on JSF 2.2

Tags: tomcat, jsf-2.2, java-6, mojarra

Good day.

I've a VPS contains Tomcat 7.0.0 and JDK 1.6.0.21-b06 on Linux Centos.
I've installed my JSF 2.2 application (Mojarra 2.2.7 and Primefaces 5.0).
When I call a ManagedBean method having parameters the above error occurs:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /homepage.xhtml @181,72 action="#{areapubblicaBean.GotoAiuto('homepage')}": Method not found: areariserv.AreapubblicaBean@161ebfb.GotoAiuto()
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
```

root cause

```
javax.faces.el.MethodNotFoundException: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /homepage.xhtml @181,72 action="#{areapubblicaBean.GotoAiuto('homepage')}": Method not found: areariserv.AreapubblicaBean@161ebfb.GotoAiuto()
    javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:91)
    com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
```

root cause

```
javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /homepage.xhtml @181,72 action="#{areapubblicaBean.GotoAiuto('homepage')}": Method not found: areariserv.AreapubblicaBean@161ebfb.GotoAiuto()
    com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:109)
    javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
```

When I developed the application in my PC environment using Tomcat 7.0.54 and JDK 1.7.0_25 all run correctly.

Why does this happen?

Best regards and good work.

Stefano Errani

Answer (score 0):

change your method name from GotoAiuto to doAction(passedString)

```
public void doAction(String param){
System.out.println(param);
}
```

and test.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried it with the same result.
When I click on buttom appears the error.

It possibile that it depend of the Java Version (6 in a vps and 7 in my pc)?

Best regards.

Stefano Errani